# Convert Battery to AC @ same voltage

Tags: led, batteries, ac, dc

I have some LED fair lights that run on 30V @ 0.4A supplied from an AC mains supply.  They have been wired to flash using some form of notification to the AC (I'm not interested in them flashing).

I want to wire them from a battery I have at 30 V (off a balance board) but a direct wiring only lights half of the lights.  If I switch the polarity the other half (only) light.

It's going outside so I don't want the original adaptor which needs a minimum of 110 V. Is there a simple fix to make this work?  It's only a simple project - so cheap and simple.

Answer (score 2):

Simple & cheap with stuff from Wallmart is to use a 12V battery, a car inverter, and the wall-wart.

Simple & cheap with stuff from DigiKey is to build a MOSFET H-bridge that's driven by a 555 timer running at 60Hz.  But that's a lot more complex than the *other* simple & cheap.  You need a pair of gate drives that have built-in shoot-through protection, you need to generate a +12V gate & control electronics supply, and you need four suitable FETs.  Then you need to wire it all up.

There *may* be a simple & cheap eBay solution that'll generate 30V square-wave AC from your 30V battery, but if there is I don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

The LED light that runs from AC is likely to be a design where LEDs are wired as pairs in antiphase. This means that DC will only illuminate 50% of the LEDs and to illuminate all the LEDs you need AC i.e. 50% of the LEDs illuminate on the positive cycle of AC and the other 50% illuminate on the negative cycle of AC. Here is an example: -

[image]

If you want all the LEDs to light you need to supply an AC voltage.

Comment: Thanks, so what's the simplest was to convert dc to ac. Is there a simple.way to do this ?

Comment: This is not an answer. The OP has already established that he needs AC. The question is, how to get it?

Comment: @PaulSlater the easiest way is to use an AC power source. If this doesn’t appear to be easy to you please explain why. You can use an inverter to convert DC power to AC. Plenty to choose from so if that is your preferred solution (after googling inverter options), let me know so that I can add that to my answer and keep the answer police at bay.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide the information on the lights wiring. Some of the LED lights have removable design, in case you need to replace them.

Try removing one bulb that does not light up. If the rest of lights will go out too then simple rotating of all non-lighted bulbs in their sockets might work for you. But then you'd need double voltage to light them up to full brightness.

Comment: Some useful info, unfortunately, cant find an off the shelf solution. I've not the skills to nock something up but thanks all !